# RSpec - Correct syntax for setting request.referrer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have in my test files:

```
controller.request.stub referer: 'bla'
```

This produces the deprecation warning:

```
Using `stub` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead.
```

What is the correct way of setting the request.referrer in controller specs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `allow(controller.request).to receive(:referer).and_return('bla')`

the `.stub` syntax is deprecated as the warning says.